Error: Could not find or load main class com.intuit.karate.Main
I installed VScode with Karate extension v2.0.5 (most recent one) + Runtime support for Java
I simply created a simple project with 1 feature file.
However, upon running I encountered below error
"Error: Could not find or load main class com.intuit.karate.Main"
I will be grateful if some experts can help me troubleshoot this so I can continue to do my PoC work. Thank you.
My screenshot
I expect to run feature file using Karate framework smoothly.
Updated: I followed the advice from below link to roll back to version 1.2.0 and it works, intriguing)
Unable to run .feature using vscode extension

Most teams use a Maven or Gradle build configuration. But if you want to avoid dealing with a Java project, you must use the "standalone JAR". Refer to the instructions here: https://github.com/karatelabs/vscode-extension#standalone
One of the Java-based projects you can try as a test is this one: karate-todo. Note that only the configuration is Java, and for writing tests and using Karate you don't need to know Java at all.

Thank you, I have downloaded JAR and put it under /jars/karate-1.5.0.RC3.jar.  In the extension setting I have used relative path => jars/karate-1.5.0.RC3.jar => still encounter the same issue.

@TonyThongsinthop do not include the jar name in the path, use only the folder - and the documentation is clear about this I hope. also make sure you switch the "Run Mode" to standalone in the settings

Ah nice! It works now. Thank you so much.

That said, I am sure there will be quite a few users who would attempt to download the karate from VSCode extension and they will definitely run into the same problem. Shouldn't this issue "Error: Could not find or load main class com.intuit.karate.Main" be classified as defect so your team can look into it? (In other words, the VS code extension for Karate itself is not working when installed). The standalone approach seems like a workaround though.

@TonyThongsinthop yes it is a hard one. as you saw in the 1.2 version days we used to "bundle" the karate binary within the plugin. but it ended up making the plugin 100 MB. we also noticed that most of the Karate users use a Java project config. but your feedback is absolutely valid, we will consider an option to prompt a user to auto-download the JAR when needed

Yes that will be awesome mate. At least you will help people save lots of time if they see an error message on the console that prompts them to go download a standalone JAR :) Appreciate your help mate :)
